# How do I set coffescript in Locomotivejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript, locomotivejs

What should I do to set coffeescript in Locomotivejs.

It seems very easy, but I couldn't figure that out.

I set options in "all.js", without luck.

I think I'm almost there or very far to get it right. :(

```
this.set("options",{coffee:true});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to add a `server.js` file and boot Locomotive with CoffeeScript support, like so:

```
locomotive = require('locomotive')

locomotive.boot('.', 'development', {"coffeeScript": true}, (err, server) -> 
  throw err if (err)

  server.listen(3000, 'localhost', ()-> 
    addr = this.address()
    console.log('listening on %s:%d', addr.address, addr.port);
  )
)
```

To start the app:

```
$ node server
```

There's more info in this pull request:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/locomotive/pull/44

Support for a --coffee option to the `lcm` command line will be added to an upcoming release.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `server.coffee` and `coffee server`?