# how do i use coffescript with locomotive JS

Tags: coffeescript, locomotivejs

Hi i'm trying to use the newest locomotiveJS version but want to use coffescripts for my controllers etc. - Old posts on google (like [How do I set coffescript in Locomotivejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489677/how-do-i-set-coffescript-in-locomotivejs)) shows that this is possible, but the examples given doesn't fit anymore (structure changes to app booting in locomotive).

An up-to-date example would be nice

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out myself, in the newer version you just have to require the coffeescript compiler and then everything works magically